# Pandas: resample timeseries with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

Given the below pandas DataFrame:

```
In [115]: times = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2014-08-25 21:00:00','2014-08-25 21:04:00',
                                            '2014-08-25 22:07:00','2014-08-25 22:09:00']))
          locations = ['HK', 'LDN', 'LDN', 'LDN']
          event = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
          df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': locations,
                             'Event': event}, index=times)
          df
Out[115]:
                               Event Location
          2014-08-25 21:00:00  foo   HK
          2014-08-25 21:04:00  bar   LDN
          2014-08-25 22:07:00  baz   LDN
          2014-08-25 22:09:00  qux   LDN
```

I would like resample the data to aggregate it hourly by count while grouping by location to produce a data frame that looks like this:

```
Out[115]:
                               HK    LDN
          2014-08-25 21:00:00  1     1
          2014-08-25 22:00:00  0     2
```

I've tried various combinations of resample() and groupby() but with no luck. How would I go about this?

Comment: For those coming to this question in 2017+, `pd.TimeGrouper` is deprecated. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186403/3707607) for the latest syntax.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In my original post, I suggested using `pd.TimeGrouper`. 
Nowadays, use `pd.Grouper` instead of `pd.TimeGrouper`. The syntax is largely the same, but `TimeGrouper` [is now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186403/190597) in favor of `pd.Grouper`.

Moreover, while `pd.TimeGrouper` could only group by DatetimeIndex, `pd.Grouper` can group by datetime *columns* which you can specify through the [`key` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas-grouper).

---

You could use a [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to group the DatetimeIndex'ed DataFrame by hour:

```
grouper = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1H'), 'Location'])
```

use `count` to count the number of events in each group:

```
grouper['Event'].count()
#                      Location
# 2014-08-25 21:00:00  HK          1
#                      LDN         1
# 2014-08-25 22:00:00  LDN         2
# Name: Event, dtype: int64
```

use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to move the `Location` index level to a column level:

```
grouper['Event'].count().unstack()
# Out[49]: 
# Location             HK  LDN
# 2014-08-25 21:00:00   1    1
# 2014-08-25 22:00:00 NaN    2
```

and then use `fillna` to change the NaNs into zeros.

---

Putting it all together,

```
grouper = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1H'), 'Location'])
result = grouper['Event'].count().unstack('Location').fillna(0)
```

yields

```
Location             HK  LDN
2014-08-25 21:00:00   1    1
2014-08-25 22:00:00   0    2
```

Comment: If you have your `DatetimeIndex` in a `MultiIndex`, use `pd.Grouper(level=datetime_level_name, freq='1H')`

Comment: In version 0.24.1 I had to write the parameter freq: `grouper = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1H'), 'Location'])`

Answer (score 54):

#### Pandas 0.21 answer: [TimeGrouper is getting deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17703)

There are two options for doing this. They actually can give different results based on your data. The first option groups by Location and within Location groups by hour. The second option groups by Location and hour at the same time.

**Option 1**: Use `groupby + resample`

```
grouped = df.groupby('Location').resample('H')['Event'].count()
```

**Option 2**: Group both the location and DatetimeIndex together with `groupby(pd.Grouper)`

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Location', pd.Grouper(freq='H')])['Event'].count()
```

They both will result in the following:

```
Location                     
HK        2014-08-25 21:00:00    1
LDN       2014-08-25 21:00:00    1
          2014-08-25 22:00:00    2
Name: Event, dtype: int64
```

And then reshape:

```
grouped.unstack('Location', fill_value=0)
```

Will output

```
Location             HK  LDN
2014-08-25 21:00:00   1    1
2014-08-25 22:00:00   0    2
```

Comment: Sorry, I know this is a old question.  How would you do this for a multiple column groupby now that TimeGrouper is getting deprecated?  Also, would be possible to specify start and end dates in addition to the intervals?

Comment: @Pylander TimeGrouper did nothing that Grouper couldn't do. Just use a list as done with option 2. You can only specify dates at regular intervals with the date offset aliases. If you have non-regular dates you will have to do some preprocessing and simply label each with each group it belongs to and then use groupby with those groups.

Comment: That makes sense.  So just to clarify on the non-regular dates.  I have a desired date range of 2004-01-01-12/31/2018 with 30 day intervals.  There are no guarantees that there will be values for every groupby key for every time interval.  Would this be a "non-regular date" problem or would I be set with this approach?

Comment: 30 day intervals are regular dates. If some of your groupby keys have different dates then each option in this answer will give you different results. It will depend on what result you desire. If you are still confused just go ahead and create a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I did end up creating a new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611626/python-pandas-resampling-multivariate-time-series-with-a-groupby

Comment: @TedPetrou Can you give an example as to how the **Option 1** and **Option 2** that you present would give different results for the same source data?  As long as they are parameterized equivalently (offset aliases, etc.), how would that be the case?

Comment: Note that Option 1 interpolates/gap-fills while Option 2 doesn't.

Answer (score 16):

#### Multiple Column Group By

untubu is spot on with his answer but I wanted to add in what you could do if you had a third column, say `Cost` and wanted to aggregate it like above. It was through combining unutbu's answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10020591) that I found out how to do this and thought I would share for future users.

Create a DataFrame with `Cost` column:

```
In[1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
times = pd.to_datetime([
    "2014-08-25 21:00:00", "2014-08-25 21:04:00",
    "2014-08-25 22:07:00", "2014-08-25 22:09:00"
])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Location": ["HK", "LDN", "LDN", "LDN"],
    "Event":    ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"],
    "Cost":     [20, 24, 34, 52]
}, index = times)
df

Out[1]:
                     Location  Event  Cost
2014-08-25 21:00:00        HK    foo    20
2014-08-25 21:04:00       LDN    bar    24
2014-08-25 22:07:00       LDN    baz    34
2014-08-25 22:09:00       LDN    qux    52
```

Now we group by using the `agg` function to specify each column's aggregation method, e.g. count, mean, sum, etc.

```
In[2]:
grp = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq = "1H"), "Location"]) \
      .agg({"Event": np.size, "Cost": np.mean})
grp

Out[2]:
                               Event  Cost
                     Location
2014-08-25 21:00:00  HK            1    20
                     LDN           1    24
2014-08-25 22:00:00  LDN           2    43
```

Then the final `unstack` with fill `NaN` with zeros and display as `int` because it's nice.

```
In[3]: 
grp.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)

Out[3]:
                    Event     Cost
Location               HK LDN   HK LDN
2014-08-25 21:00:00     1   1   20  24
2014-08-25 22:00:00     0   2    0  43
```

Answer (score 7):

## If you want to keep all the columns

```py
df = (df.groupby("Location")
      .resample("H", on="date")
      .last()
      .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without using `resample` or `Grouper` as follows:

`df.groupby([df.index.floor("1H"), "Location"]).count()`

Comment: @exan I disagree - the other solutions use `Grouper` - this one does not. Can you point to the answer that this one duplicates?

Comment: I noticed and tried to remove down vote but system doesn't allow to change ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

`pd.resample` >>> `pd.groupby()` seems to be the quite faster by many times

```
df = 

PJMW_MW
Datetime    
2002-04-01 01:00:00     4374.0
2002-04-01 02:00:00     4306.0
2002-04-01 03:00:00     4322.0
2002-04-01 04:00:00     4359.0
2002-04-01 05:00:00     4436.0
...     ...
2017-12-31 19:00:00     8205.0
2017-12-31 20:00:00     8053.0
2017-12-31 21:00:00     8012.0
2017-12-31 22:00:00     7864.0
2017-12-31 23:00:00     7710.0

138066 rows × 1 columns

%timeit df.resample(rule='24H', kind='interval').mean()
3.45 ms ± 41.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).mean()
169 ms ± 1.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```