# Pandas Resample on Date Columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `dataframe` with dates as columns. I'd like to average the values from daily to a monthly level. I've tried with Time Grouper and Resample, but it doesn't like the columns names are strings and I can seem to figure out how to make columns into something like a `DatetimeIndex`.

My starting dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],
                  columns=['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-02-03', '2013-02-04'], 
                  index=['A', 'B'])
```

Desired Output:

```
   2013-01-01  2013-02-01
A         1.5         3.5
B         5.6         7.5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can using `resample`

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df.T.resample('M').mean().T
Out[409]: 
   2013-01-31  2013-02-28
A         1.5         3.5
B         5.5         7.5
```

Or `groupby` one

```
axis=1 
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period('M'),1).mean()
Out[412]: 
   2013-01  2013-02
A      1.5      3.5
B      5.5      7.5
```

Answer (score 4):

First, convert column index to datetime with `pd.to_datetime`, then use `T` and `groupby` with `pd.Grouper` (note [pd.TimeGerouper is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186403/6361531) use pd.Grouper):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df.T.groupby(by=pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).mean().T
```

Output:

```
   2013-01-01  2013-02-01
A         1.5         3.5
B         5.5         7.5
```

Answer (score 4):

you can make use of [pd.PeriodIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.html):

```
In [145]: df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='M'), axis=1).mean()
Out[145]:
   2013-01  2013-02
A      1.5      3.5
B      5.5      7.5
```

Comment: @MaxU agree :-)

Comment: Now, I understand ..Your method is much more neat :-) learn new thing :~) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the column names to date first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], columns=pd.to_datetime(['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-02-03', '2013-02-04']), index=['A', 'B'])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

list=df.columns
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(int(0.5*len(list))):
    df_new[list[2*i]] = (df[[list[2*i], list[2*i+1]]].mean(axis=1))
```

Output

```
       2013-01-01  2013-02-03
A         1.5         3.5
B         5.5         7.5
```

I dont understand your Desired Output:

Comment: it's the monthly mean.

Comment: Yes, for '2013-01-01' the average is 1.5 ((1+2)/2) and 5.5 ((5+6)/2), but for 2013-02-01  the average is 2.5 ((2+3)/2) and 6.5 ((6+7)/2), and you use 3.5 ((3+4)/2) and 7.5 ((7+8)/2).

Comment: it's not daily. it's monthly. have a look below answers, the index is on 'Month'. i.e. Jan and Feb. January, column A has an avarege of (1+2)/2 = 1.5. February, column A has an average of (3+4)/2 = 3.5. you get the rest I believe.