# How to remove duplicate entries from a dataframe based on timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, timestamp

In this task I have a data frame with timestamp and a service message that is a request of some service, this column has multiple entries of same message in a short period of time because the message keeps on generating until service is accepted or rejected. here is sample dataframe -

```
timestamp                   service message
2019-02-15 15:56:19         battery check
2019-02-15 15:56:34         battery check
2019-02-15 15:57:02         battery check
2019-02-15 15:57:30         battery check
2019-02-15 15:57:54         battery check
2019-02-15 15:59:10         battery check
2019-02-15 17:05:03         battery check
2019-02-15 17:05:42         battery check
2019-02-15 17:06:40         no network available
2019-02-15 17:06:48         no network available
2019-02-15 17:06:58         no network available
2019-02-15 17:08:31         no network available
```

I want to remove all duplicates let's say in a 15 min time frame, so that can be counted as 1 service.
but simple string check not working since message at `17:05:03` is different from previous since there is more than an hour difference.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas resample documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001389/pandas-resample-documentation)

Comment: Another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47704702/6692898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with column `service message` for aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
print (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='15min', key='timestamp'), 'service message']).first())
                                                   timestamp
timestamp           service message                         
2019-02-15 15:45:00 battery check        2019-02-15 15:56:19
2019-02-15 17:00:00 battery check        2019-02-15 17:05:03
                    no network available 2019-02-15 17:06:40
```

---

```
df1 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='15min', key='timestamp'), 
                 'service message'])
         .first()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
        service message           timestamp
0         battery check 2019-02-15 15:56:19
1         battery check 2019-02-15 17:05:03
2  no network available 2019-02-15 17:06:40
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use `boolean masking` to remove the duplicates:

```
m1 = df['timestamp'].diff().le(pd.Timedelta(minutes=15))
m2 = df['service message'].duplicated() & \
     df['service message'].eq(df['service message'].shift())

df = df[~(m1 & m2)]
```

**Details:**

```
print(m1)
0     False
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool

print(m2)
0     False
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8     False
9      True
10     True
11     True
Name: service message, dtype: bool
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)
            timestamp       service message
0 2019-02-15 15:56:19         battery check
6 2019-02-15 17:05:03         battery check
8 2019-02-15 17:06:40  no network available
```