# I'm trying to create a frequency table of some dates with pandas TimeGrouper however it returns error

Tags: python, pandas, time

I'm trying to create frequency table from some dates by pandas TimeGrouper but I receive the following error

**input:**

```
t = pd.to_datetime(t)

t = pd.Series(t)

t
```

**output:**

```
0   2019-04-10 10:49:00

1   2019-04-10 10:49:00

2   2019-04-10 10:49:00

3   2019-04-10 10:49:00

4   2019-04-10 10:49:00

5   2019-04-10 10:48:00

6   2019-04-10 10:48:00

7   2019-04-10 10:48:00

8   2019-04-10 10:48:00

9   2019-04-10 10:48:00

Name: tweet.created_at, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**input:**

```
t.groupby(pd.core.resample.TimeGrouper('H').count().plot(kind='bar'))
```

**output:**

```
Error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Comment: 'TimeGrouper' is deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186403/6361531

Comment: uhum. now I wend through your link and used this: t.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H')).count().plot() again the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this trick to get around:

```
t.reset_index().set_index(t.name).resample('H').count().plot()
```

Comment: uhum. it returned the following error:  return self._engine.get_loc(key). Key Error: 1

Comment: Sorry, that's because `t` has different name, try `set_index('tweet.created_at')` instead of `set_index(1)`.

Comment: Or more generally `set_index(t.name)`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot man! It worked. I LOVE YOU. Long live China!

Comment: 1. I have nothing to do with China. 2. If it works, consider upvote and accept the answer :-).

Comment: 1. Long live Vietnam* 2. Sure bro. I voted but since my level is not high yet, the website said that my vote will be considered but not displayed. Thanks a lot again!