# Resample with categories in pandas, keep non-numerical columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have hourly data, of variable `x` for 3 types, and `Category` column, and `ds` is set as index.

```
> df

ds                   Category   X
2010-01-01 01:00:00     A       32
2010-01-01 01:00:00     B       13
2010-01-01 01:00:00     C       09
2010-01-01 02:00:00     A       12
2010-01-01 02:00:00     B       62
2010-01-01 02:00:00     C       12
```

I want to resample it to `Week`. But if I use `df2 = df.resample('W').mean()`, it simply drops 'Category' Column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: resample timeseries with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012012/pandas-resample-timeseries-with-groupby)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If need `resample` per `Category` column per weeks add `groupby`, so is using [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

*Notice*:
For correct working is necessary `DatetimeIndex`.

```
df2 = df.groupby('Category').resample('W').mean()
print (df2)
                        X
Category ds              
A        2010-01-03  22.0
B        2010-01-03  37.5
C        2010-01-03  10.5
```

Answer (score 6):

To complete the [answer by jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56001953/3751268), I found it useful to put the content back as a DataFrame instead of a DataFrameGroup, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56001953/3751268). So, the answer will be:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Category').resample('W').mean()

# the inverse of groupby, reset_index
df2 = df2.reset_index()

# set again the timestamp as index
df2 = df2.set_index("ds")
```