# Upsampling a polars dataframe with groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, python-polars, rust-polars

I'm trying to upsample a Polars dataframe while grouping by a particular column. In the following example, I wish to group by 'fruit' and then upsample by date.

| fruit | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-06-01 | 5 |
| apple | 2022-06-03 | 6 |
| apple | 2022-06-04 | 2 |
| apple | 2022-06-07 | 1 |
| pear | 2022-06-01 | 9 |
| pear | 2022-06-07 | 12 |

This is what the output should look like:

| fruit | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-06-01 | 5 |
| apple | 2022-06-02 | 5 |
| apple | 2022-06-03 | 6 |
| apple | 2022-06-04 | 2 |
| apple | 2022-06-05 | 2 |
| apple | 2022-06-06 | 2 |
| apple | 2022-06-07 | 1 |
| pear | 2022-06-01 | 9 |
| pear | 2022-06-02 | 9 |
| pear | 2022-06-03 | 9 |
| pear | 2022-06-04 | 9 |
| pear | 2022-06-05 | 9 |
| pear | 2022-06-06 | 9 |
| pear | 2022-06-07 | 12 |

For a non group-by scenario, the following command gets me the result I need:

```
df.upsample('date', every='1d').fill_null("forward")
```

However, I've not been able to get it working when a groupby is involved

ps: here is a similar question, but using pandas - [Pandas: resample timeseries with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012012/pandas-resample-timeseries-with-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the `upsample` function has a `'by'` parameter that gives me the results that I need. [Here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.upsample.html#polars.DataFrame.upsample) is a link to API docs for the `.upsample()` method.