# AttributeError: module 'pandas.tseries.offsets' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Tags: python, pandas

my version of pandas is 1.1.3, and I'm trying to run code obtained from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597926/converting-daily-stock-data-to-weekly-based-via-pandas-in-python) but

```
offset = pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6)
```

gives the error mentioned in my title, timedelta has been imported but no luck. How can I get this to run properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is warning:

> FutureWarning: 'loffset' in .resample() and in Grouper() is deprecated.

You can change solution with subtract `6` days after `resample`:

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

df = df.resample('W').apply(logic)
df.index -= to_offset("6D")
#alternative
#df.index = df.index - to_offset("6D")

print (df)
                 Open       High        Low      Close   Volume
Date                                                           
2010-01-04  38.660000  40.700001  38.509998  40.290001  5925600
2010-01-11  40.209999  40.970001  39.279999  40.450001  6234600
```

Comment: first I had to change pd.offsets.timedelta to pd.timedelta before getting the warning. Solution works thank you!