# Convert daily data to weekly by taking average of the 7 days

Tags: python, pandas

I've created the following datafram from data given on CDC [link](https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#trends_dailycases_select_00).

```
googledata = pd.read_csv('/content/data_table_for_daily_case_trends__the_united_states.csv', header=2) 
# Inspect data
googledata.head()
```

| id | State | Date | New Cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | United States | Oct 2 2022 | 11553 |
| 1 | United States | Oct 1 2022 | 8024 |
| 2 | United States | Sep 30 2022 | 46383 |
| 3 | United States | Sep 29 2022 | 89873 |
| 4 | United States | Sep 28 2022 | 63763 |

After converting the date column to datetime and trimming the data for the last 1 year by implementing the mask operation I got the data in the last 1 year:

```
googledata['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(googledata['Date'])

df = googledata
start_date = '2021-10-1'
end_date = '2022-10-1'
mask = (df['Date'] > start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date)
  
df = df.loc[mask]
```

But the problem is I am getting the data in terms of days, but I wish to convert this data in terms of weeks ; i.e converting the 365 rows to 52 rows corresponding to weeks data taking mean of `New cases` the 7 days in 1 week's data.

I tried implementing the following method as shown in the previous post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597926/converting-daily-stock-data-to-weekly-based-via-pandas-in-python) I don't think I am even applying this correctly! Because this code is not asking me to put my dataframe anywhere!

```
logic = {'New Cases'  : 'mean'}

offset = pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6)

f = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
f.resample('W', loffset=offset).apply(logic)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas.tseries.offsets' has no attribute
> 'timedelta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you want to [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
df = df.set_index("Date")
df.index = df.index - pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset("6D")
df = df.resample("W").agg({"New Cases": "mean"}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use strftime to convert date to week number before applying groupby

```
df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
df.groupby('Week')['New Cases'].mean()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. But will that create a dataframe? I think it will create a series. Now how to get back to dataframe from there?

Comment: Also, the Week column seems not be in the original date-time format. like Y-M-D. Anyway how to overcome that?

Comment: You can use transform() to create a new column then drop_duplicates(), for the Week column if you want Y-M-D format which date do you want for the week?