# insert new non-existing column in how= of resample

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I was reading [resample a dataframe with different functions applied to each column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020591/how-to-resample-a-dataframe-with-different-functions-applied-to-each-column)

The solution was:

```
frame.resample('1H', how={'radiation': np.sum, 'tamb': np.mean})
```

Say if I want to add a non-existing column to the result that stores the value of some other function, say count(). In the example given, say if I want to compute the number of rows in each 1H period.

Is it possible to do:

```
frame.resample('1H', how={'radiation': np.sum, 'tamb': np.mean,\
               'new_column': count()})
```

Note, new_column is NOT an existing column in the original data frame.

The reason why I ask, is I need to do this and I have a very large data frame and I don't want to resample the original df twice just to get the count in the resample period.

I'm trying the above right now and it seems to be taking a very long time (no syntax errors). Not sure if python is trapped in some sort of forever loop.

Update:

I implemented the suggestion to use agg (thank you kindly for that).

However, I received the following error when computing the first aggregator:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['name1',pd.TimeGrouper('M')])
    return pd.DataFrame(
    {'new_col1': grouped['col1'][grouped['col1'] > 0].agg('sum')
    ...


/Users/blahblah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    521 
    522     def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 523         raise NotImplementedError('Not implemented: %s' % key)
    524 
    525     def _make_wrapper(self, name):

NotImplementedError: Not implemented: True
```

The following works when I use `grouped.apply(foo)`.

```
new_col1 = grp['col1'][grp['col1'] > 0].sum()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resampling` is similar to grouping with a `TimeGrouper`.  While `resampling`'s
`how` parameter only allows you to specify one aggregator per column,
The `GroupBy` object returned by `df.groupby(...)` has an `agg` method which can be passed various functions (e.g. `mean`, `sum`, or `count`) to aggregate the groups in various ways. You can use these results to build the desired DataFrame:

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

date_times = pd.date_range(DT.datetime(2012, 4, 5, 8, 0),
                           DT.datetime(2012, 4, 5, 12, 0),
                           freq='1min')
tamb = np.random.sample(date_times.size) * 10.0
radiation = np.random.sample(date_times.size) * 10.0
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'tamb': tamb, 'radiation': radiation},
                  index=date_times)

resampled = df.resample('1H', how={'radiation': np.sum, 'tamb': np.mean})
print(resampled[['radiation', 'tamb']])
#                       radiation      tamb
# 2012-04-05 08:00:00  279.432788  4.549235
# 2012-04-05 09:00:00  310.032188  4.414302
# 2012-04-05 10:00:00  257.504226  5.056613
# 2012-04-05 11:00:00  299.594032  4.652067
# 2012-04-05 12:00:00    8.109946  7.795668

def using_agg(df):
    grouped = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H'))
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {'radiation': grouped['radiation'].agg('sum'), 
         'tamb': grouped['tamb'].agg('mean'), 
         'new_column': grouped['tamb'].agg('count')})

print(using_agg(df))
```

yields

```
                     new_column   radiation      tamb
2012-04-05 08:00:00          60  279.432788  4.549235
2012-04-05 09:00:00          60  310.032188  4.414302
2012-04-05 10:00:00          60  257.504226  5.056613
2012-04-05 11:00:00          60  299.594032  4.652067
2012-04-05 12:00:00           1    8.109946  7.795668
```

---

Note my first answer suggested using `groupby/apply`:

```
def using_apply(df):
    grouped = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H'))
    result = grouped.apply(foo).unstack(-1)
    result = result.sortlevel(axis=1)
    return result[['radiation', 'tamb', 'new_column']]

def foo(grp):
    radiation = grp['radiation'].sum()
    tamb = grp['tamb'].mean()
    cnt = grp['tamb'].count()
    return pd.Series([radiation, tamb, cnt], index=['radiation', 'tamb', 'new_column'])
```

It turns out that using `apply` here is much slower than using `agg`. If we benchmark `using_agg` versus `using_apply` on a 1681-row DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(2016)

date_times = pd.date_range(DT.datetime(2012, 4, 5, 8, 0),
                           DT.datetime(2012, 4, 6, 12, 0),
                           freq='1min')
tamb = np.random.sample(date_times.size) * 10.0
radiation = np.random.sample(date_times.size) * 10.0
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'tamb': tamb, 'radiation': radiation},
                  index=date_times)
```

I find using IPython's `%timeit` function

```
In [83]: %timeit using_apply(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop

In [84]: %timeit using_agg(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop
```

`using_agg` is significantly faster than `using_apply` and (based on additional
`%timeit` tests) the speed advantage in favor of `using_agg` grows as `len(df)`
grows.

---

By the way, regarding

```
frame.resample('1H', how={'radiation': np.sum, 'tamb': np.mean,\
               'new_column': count()})
```

besides the problem that the `how` dict does not accept non-existant column names, the parentheses in `count` are problematic. The values in the `how` dict should be function objects. `count` is a function object, but `count()` is the value returned by calling `count`.

Since Python evaluates arguments *before* calling functions, `count()` is getting called before `frame.resample(...)`, and the return value of `count()` is then associated with the key `'new_column'` in the dict bound to the `how` parameter. That's not what you want.

---

Regarding the updated question: Precompute the values that you will need *before* calling `groupby/agg`:

Instead of

```
grouped = df.groupby(['name1',pd.TimeGrouper('M')])
return pd.DataFrame(
    {'new_col1': grouped['col1'][grouped['col1'] > 0].agg('sum')
     ...
# ImplementationError since `grouped['col1']` does not implement __getitem__
```

use

```
df['col1_pos'] = df['col1'].clip(lower=0)
grouped = df.groupby(['name1',pd.TimeGrouper('M')])
return pd.DataFrame(
    {'new_col1': grouped['col1_pos'].agg('sum')
    ...
```

See the [bottom of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341363/190597) for more on why pre-computation helps performance.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and thoughtful explanation. I truly appreciate it. The answer is taught me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Question: is there a difference in how each of the aggregator per column operations are performed versus the sequential computation of aggregators in foo(grp). In my case I have 30 aggregators in foo(grp) which takes a long time because it has to iterate through each aggregator at a time over the same set of groups. Not sure if how= works the same way. I am wondering if there is a way to vectorize the computation for speed?

Comment: Indeed, I think my first suggestion to use `apply` was not a good one. There is a much faster way: use `groupby/agg` instead of `groupby/apply`. I've edited my post to show what I mean.

Comment: Wow. Great thank you solution to use agg. I appreciate it. It seems I've run into another problem with the way I compute aggregators. I want to compute .agg('sum') for positive and negative values in separate columns.  I was able to do this when using the apply(foo) method (but not optimal as you know).

Comment: You may need to precompute new columns with just the positive values in one column and the negative values in the another column. Then you can apply `groupby/agg('sum')` to these new columns .

Comment: Your updated solution works amazing. It is lightening fast compared to what I had before. Thank you.