# how to get multiple conditional operations after a Pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : [12,10,-2,-4,-2,5,8,7],
                   'C' : [-5,5,-20,0,1,5,4,-4]})

df
Out[12]: 
     A   B   C
0  foo  12  -5
1  bar  10   5
2  foo  -2 -20
3  bar  -4   0
4  foo  -2   1
5  bar   5   5
6  foo   8   4
7  foo   7  -4
```

Here I need to compute, for **each group in A**, the sum of elements **in B** **conditional on C being non-negative** (i.e. being >=0,  a condition based on another column). And vice-versa for C.

However, my code below fails.

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': lambda x: x[x.C>0].sum(),
                     'C': lambda x: x[x.B>0].sum()})      

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'B'
```

So it seems `apply` would be preferred (because apply *sees* all the dataframe I think), but unfortunately I cannot use a dictionary with `apply`. So I am stuck. Any ideas?

One not-so-pretty not-so-efficient solution would be to create these conditional variables before running the `groupby`, but I am sure this solution does not use the potential of **`Pandas`**.

So, for instance, the expected output for the group `bar` and `column B` would be

```
+10 (indeed C equals 5 and is >=0)
-4 (indeed C equals 0 and is >=0)
+5 = 11
```

Another example:
group `foo` and `column B`

```
NaN (indeed C equals -5 so I dont want to consider the 12 value in B)
+ NaN   (indeed C= -20)
-2    (indeed C=1 so its positive)
+ 8
+NaN = 6
```

Remark that I use `NaNs` instead of zero because another function than a sum would give wrong results (median) if we were to put zeros.

In other words, this is a simple conditional sum where the condition is based on another column.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
print df.groupby('A').agg({'B': lambda x: df.loc[x.index, 'C'][x >= 0].sum(), 
                           'C': lambda x: df.loc[x.index, 'B'][x >= 0].sum()})  
      C   B
A          
bar  11  10
foo   6  -5
```

Better for understanding are custom function what is same as above:

```
def f(x):
    s = df.loc[x.index, 'C']
    return s[x>=0].sum()
def f1(x):
    s = df.loc[x.index, 'B']
    return s[x>=0].sum()


print df.groupby('A').agg({'B': f, 'C': f1})
      C   B
A          
bar  11  10
foo   6  -5
```

EDIT:

root's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337773/2901002) is very nice, but it can be better:

```
def my_func(row):
    b = row[row.C >= 0].B.sum()
    c = row[row.B >= 0].C.sum()
    return pd.Series({'C':b, 'B':c})

result = df.groupby('A').apply(my_func)
      C   B
A          
bar  11  10
foo   6  -5
```

Comment: thanks jezrael but I dont think this works. I am conditioning on the **other variable** in the sum.

Comment: thank you so much. can you just explain the mechanism here? what does `df.loc[x.index, 'C'][df.loc[x.index,'C'] > 0]` exactly do?

Comment: Is the output correct?  For example, shouldn't (foo, 'B') be 6? Or am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: yes, I think the output is not correct actually. Let me make the question more clear. But I believe the solution will be very close

Comment: thanks jezrael, If I am not mistaken, didnt you erroneously switch B and C in your second example?

Comment: @jezrael In SQL we use `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tb.A > tb.B THEN tb.C ELSE NULL END) AS cnt`, how to reach this?

Comment: @mingchau - Without data not easy, but something like `out = df.loc[df.A > df.B, 'C'].nunique()` shuld working, if not, please post new question with sample data, expected output and your code, what you try.

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative is to precompute the values you will need before using `groupby/agg`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar'], replace=True, size=(N,)),
                   'B' : np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(N,)),
                   'C' : np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(N,))})

def using_precomputation(df):
    df['B2'] = df['B'] * (df['C'] >= 0).astype(int)
    df['C2'] = df['C'] * (df['B'] >= 0).astype(int)
    result = df.groupby('A').agg({'B2': 'sum', 'C2': 'sum'})   
    return result.rename(columns={'B2':'B', 'C2':'C'})
```

Let's compare `using_precomputation` with `using_index` and `using_apply`:

```
def using_index(df):
    result = df.groupby('A').agg({'B': lambda x: df.loc[x.index, 'C'][x >= 0].sum(), 
                                  'C': lambda x: df.loc[x.index, 'B'][x >= 0].sum()}) 
    return result.rename(columns={'B':'C', 'C':'B'})

def my_func(row):
    b = row[row.C >= 0].B.sum()
    c = row[row.B >= 0].C.sum()
    return pd.Series({'B':b, 'C':c})

def using_apply(df):
    return df.groupby('A').apply(my_func)
```

First, let's check that they all return the same result:

```
def is_equal(df, func1, func2):
    result1 = func1(df).sort_index(axis=1)
    result2 = func2(df).sort_index(axis=1)
    assert result1.equals(result2)
is_equal(df, using_precomputation, using_index)
is_equal(df, using_precomputation, using_apply)
```

---

Using the 1000-row DataFrame above:

```
In [83]: %timeit using_precomputation(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.45 ms per loop

In [84]: %timeit using_index(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.2 ms per loop

In [85]: %timeit using_apply(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.84 ms per loop
```

---

**Why is `using_precomputation` faster?**

Precomputation allows us to take advantage of fast vectorized arithmetic on
*entire columns* and allows the aggregation function to be the simple builtin
`sum`. Builtin aggregators tend to be faster than custom aggregation functions
such as the ones used here (based on jezrael's solution):

```
def using_index(df):
    result = df.groupby('A').agg({'B': lambda x: df.loc[x.index, 'C'][x >= 0].sum(), 
                                  'C': lambda x: df.loc[x.index, 'B'][x >= 0].sum()}) 
    return result.rename(columns={'B':'C', 'C':'B'})
```

Moreover, the less work you have to do on each little group, the better off you
are performance-wise. Having to do double-indexing for each group hurts performance.

Also a killer to performance is using `groupby/apply(func)` where the `func`
returns a `Series`. This forms one Series for each row of the result, and then
causes Pandas to align and concatenate all the Series. Since typically the
Series tend to be short and the number of Series tends to be big, concatenating
all these little Series tends to be slow. Again, you tend to get the best
performance out of Pandas/NumPy when performing *vectorized operations on
big arrays*. Looping through lots of tiny results kills performance.

Comment: thank you, very instructive. dont you mean this form one series for each COLUMN of the result?

Comment: Re: *This forms one Series for each row of the result*: `groupby/agg(func)` calls `func` once for each group and `func` returns a Series. Loosely speaking, the Series gets laid out horizontally and then concatenated. So each Series corresponds to a row of the result returned by `groupby/agg(func)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to return a tuple containing the fields you want, and then use `zip` to unpack them.

```
def my_func(row):
    b = row[row.C >= 0].B.sum()
    c = row[row.B >= 0].C.sum()
    return b, c

# Perform the groupby aggregation.
result = df.groupby('A').apply(my_func).to_frame()

# Unpack the resulting tuple and drop the extra column.
result['B'], result['C'] = zip(*result[0])
result.drop(0, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This yields the following output:

```
      B   C
A          
bar  11  10
foo   6  -5
```