# Groupby and count the number of unique values (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, unique

I have a dataframe with 2 variables: `ID` and `outcome`. I'm trying to `groupby` `ID` first, and count the number of unique values of `outcome` within that `ID`.

```
df
ID    outcome
1      yes
1      yes
1      yes
2      no
2      yes
2      no
```

Expected output:

```
ID    yes    no
1      3     0
2      1     2
```

My code `df[['PID', 'outcome']].groupby('PID')['outcome'].nunique()` gives the number of the unique value itself, such that:

```
ID
1   2
2   2
```

But I need the counts of the `yes` and `no`, how can I achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)?

```
In [1217]: pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.outcome)
Out[1217]: 
outcome  no  yes
ID              
1         0    3
2         2    1
```

Comment: I have to find a new **Option 2**

Comment: @piRSquared It was only a matter of time before someone else figured out this was possible :p

Comment: How about? This is great!

Comment: @Kay Cheers. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Option 2**
`pd.factorize` + `np.bincount`
This is convoluted and painful... but very fast.

```
fi, ui = pd.factorize(df.ID.values)
fo, uo = pd.factorize(df.outcome.values)

n, m = ui.size, uo.size
pd.DataFrame(
    np.bincount(fi * m + fo, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m),
    pd.Index(ui, name='ID'), pd.Index(uo, name='outcome')
)

outcome  yes  no
ID              
1          3   0
2          1   2
```

---

**Option C**

```
pd.get_dummies(d.ID).T.dot(pd.get_dummies(d.outcome))

   no  yes
1   0    3
2   2    1
```

---

**Option IV**.

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'outcome']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: that means "Terrible" hahaha

Comment: @Kay transpose of the dataframe

Answer (score 3):

Group on the `ID` column and then aggregate using `value_counts` on the `outcome` column.  This would result in a series, so you need to convert it back to a dataframe using `.to_frame()` so that you can unstack the yes/no (i.e. have them as columns).  Then fill null values with zero.

```
df_total = df.groupby('ID')['outcome'].value_counts().to_frame().unstack(fill_value=0)
df_total.columns = df_total.columns.droplevel()
>>> df_total
outcome  no  yes
ID              
1         0    3
2         2    1
```

Comment: @piRSquared Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_index` and `pd.concat`

```
df1 = df.set_index('ID')
pd.concat([df1.outcome.eq('yes').sum(level=0),
          df1.outcome.ne('yes').sum(level=0)], keys=['yes','no'],axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID  yes   no
0   1  3.0  0.0
1   2  1.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

the MOST efficient setup, that will prevent any past, present and future bugs and take advantage of FAST vectorized functions is to do the (insanely simple) following thing:

```
df['dummy_yes'] = df.outcome == 'yes'
df['dummy_no'] = df.outcome == 'no'

df.groupby('ID').sum()
```

Comment: Why do you think the other solutions will cause past, present, or future bugs?

Comment: this is something that works in any language. I had some severe and subtle bugs in the past when trying to do more pandonic stuff

Comment: @coldspeed here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337012/how-to-get-multiple-conditional-operations-after-a-pandas-groupby